# When using setResultsName with listAllMatches true, some matched items are nested

Tags: python, pyparsing

Based on this grammar:

```
from pyparsing import *

g = quotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )
eg = Suppress('-') + quotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )
choice = Or( [ g.setResultsName("out",listAllMatches=True),     
              eg.setResultsName("in",listAllMatches=True) ] )
grammar = ZeroOrMore( choice ) + Suppress(restOfLine)

a = world.parseString( ' "ali"  -"baba"  "holy cow"   -"smoking beaute"  ' )
print a.dump()
```

I have discovered that tokens that satisfy the `eg` nonterminal are always wrapped in an extra list. The only difference with `g` is that it has a leading `Suppress('-')'.

```
['ali', 'baba', 'holy cow', 'smoking beaute']
- in: [['baba'], ['smoking beaute']]
- out: ['ali', 'holy cow']
```

How do make them behave the same ? I want to achieve the result below:

```
['ali', 'baba', 'holy cow', 'smoking beaute']
- in: ['baba', 'smoking beaute']
- out: ['ali', 'holy cow']
```

Comment: There is no reason for using Or here, a MatchFirst is unambiguous, and does better at short-circuiting. I'm also sorry to see that the operator syntax is not to your liking, I think it really helps the readability of the grammars - but to each his/her/its own.

Comment: The next release of pyparsing will allow you to set results names with listAllMatches=True using the form: `choice = Or( [ g("out*"),eg("in*")] )`  Is this really preferable to `choice = g("out*") | eg("in*")` ?  Well, it's your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've looked at this issue - the problem is that And's always return their tokens as lists, even if the contain only a single value.

Here is an ungrouper that can clear this up for you, I'll include this in the next pyparsing release:

```
ungroup = lambda expr : TokenConverter(expr).setParseAction(lambda t:t[0])
eg = ungroup(Suppress('-') + quotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes ))
```

With your test code, I now get these results:

```
['ali', 'baba', 'holy cow', 'smoking beaute']
- in: ['baba', 'smoking beaute']
- out: ['ali', 'holy cow']
```

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by adding a Combine to quoteString expression. But the ungroup helper does look useful.